# C-library invoking a kdb function from a BG-thread

Tags: c, multithreading, kdb

I have an external C-library for asynchronously consuming data via callback functions on a background thread; I want to receive the data and process it in a q process. Following code.kx.com's [Interfacing with C](http://code.kx.com/q//interfaces/c-client-for-q/) documentation, I made a small C-library of glue code converting the inbound source data into k structures and dispatching it to my q process vi sd1/sd0 calls so that the q function gets invoked on q's thread context. The program successfully invokes the initial callback then hangs.

I've stripped down the program to what I think is the bare minimum to simply demonstrate a C BG-thread callback into a q function, but I'm not sure if I've stripped away too much. For example, sd1 accepts a FD and a C-callback. My bare minimum FD is created via eventfd(), which is used for subsequent sd1/sd0 calls. I have tried invoking read and write on the FD, and not doing any IO over the FD, either way the program hangs.

Here's my bare-bones C-library:

```
/* testlib.c */
#define KXVER 3
#include "k.h"
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/eventfd.h>
I d;
pthread_t tid;
K qdisp(I d)
{
        K ignored = k(0, (S)"onCB", kj(54321), (K)0);
        sd0(d);
        return (K)0;
}
void* loop(void* vargs)
{
        while(1) {
                sleep(1);
                sd1(d, qdisp);
        }
        return NULL;
}
K init(K ignore)
{
        d = eventfd(1, 0);
        int err = pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &loop, NULL);
        return (K)0;
}
```

And here's the q script that invokes it:

```
/ testlib.q
init:`testlib 2:(`init;1)
onCB:{ 0N!x }
init[`blah]
```

Any tips or comments appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those interested, it looks like sd1 schedules a function to be invoked every time there is data available to be read on a file descriptor, and sd0 removes the scheduled function from invocation.

So the idea is to write a function that attempts to read from the FD; if successful, invoke your q function via k() and return the result, if 0 just return 0, and if error call sd0.

```
#define KXVER 3
#include "k.h"
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/eventfd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
I d;
pthread_t tid;
K qdisp(I d)
{
    J v;
    if (-1 != read(d, &v, sizeof(J)) ) {
        return k(0, "onCB", ki(v), (K)0);
    }
    sd0(d);
    return (K)0;
}
void* loop(void* vargs)
{
    J j = 0;
    sd1(d, qdisp);
    while(j++) {
        sleep(1);
        write(d, &j, sizeof(J));
    }
    return NULL;
}
K init(K cb)
{
    d = eventfd(1, 0);
    int err = pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &loop, NULL);
    return (K)0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the other side provides enough data? As I see from the documentation referenced by you, communication is done by using **blocking** pipes. This means that if there is not enough data, or the buffer is not flushed by the producer, you application **should** block and this is its intended behavior.
You could try to use `sd0()/sd1()` skipping the `d` parameter to verify that the observed behavior is caused by blocking pipe and not by something else.

Comment: Thanks Artur -- I think you're right it has something to do with that blocking nature. FWIW, I tried both blocking and nonblocking (just pass `-d`) with the same effect. But you did draw my attention more closely to the documentation where I think the real problem is that sd0 closes d:

"New in kdb+ 3.0 2013.04.04: K sd0x(I d,I f) same functionality 
as sd0(I d) but f specifies whether to close d. sd0 closes d."